# PhoneGap Application Testing issues on BlackBerry 9220 OS 7.1

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

We are working on a PhoneGap2.9 application for BlackBerry 6,7 and 10 and we are testing it on Curve 9220 with OS 7.1 and it is taking 25 minutes to put the application onto device using "BlackBerry Desktop Manager" and this whole process it time consuming

We would like to know if there are any better ways to do it

any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Rash

Comment: How large is your application (in MB)?

Comment: I've loaded 3MB apps with desktop manager and didn't take more than a minute. You might have a different problem. Anyway, try javaloader.exe instead (it is included in the JDK).